# Asp.net mvc 3: WebGrid and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I have a quick question. Is it possible to put JavaScript into a cell when using MVC 3 WebGrid? I've been trying for days to figure out if this is possible, and I am having no luck.

My situation is simple: I have a WebGrid that displays data on songs that are contained in a database. So in that webgrid I have things like the title of the song, the duration, etc., but I am stuck as to how I am going to add a JavaScript audio player that plays the song of the current row in the WebGrid.

Anyway, that's the situation, and I hope you can help me. If it is possible to place JavaScript into a WebGrid, please explain how or at least point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the script don't need to be inside the grid, it can be somewhere else and reference the cell through it's id.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I had already tried placing the javascript outside of the WebGrid. I guess what I mean to ask is, how do I go about getting the cell's id? Currently I've been using a div to placehold the id of the song, and then using that same id in the javascript. But I don't think you can place a div inside a WebGrid like that can you? Well anyway, what would you recommend for me to do to reference the cell's id in the javascript?

Comment: You can use a custom column, but remember that using the classic MVC construct is much more customizeable and easy to understand than automated constructions like webgrid.